# Is it possible to capture the user name or ID of the person uploading an Oracle WebADI document?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm creating an [Oracle WebADI upload](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiv9auWl-jTAhUB5IMKHZWOANgQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.oracle.com%2Fstevenchan%2Fbuild-custom-webadi-integrators-with-ebs-1212-desktop-integration-framework&usg=AFQjCNEx7miNzZZywykzK3UPyJN3fA8C_Q&sig2=LGhNQQGJaESMD-sAfCbp-A) for users to upload PO tracking information that they get on the fly. I've created custom tables for this, and would like to grab the users' usernames and/or IDs for the 'who' columns.

Anyone out there know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it's passed in, the only thing I can think of is to check the environment varialbes, for example:

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') FROM DUAL;

select sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') from dual;
```

check docs for Predefined Parameters of Namespace USERENV